# "As man and wife"? Where is the articles?

Tags: articles

> - I can't hold a conversation with her as man and wife.

Is it not supposed to be "as a man and a wife"?

Answer (score 1):

"Man and wife" [is a set phrase](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/i-now-pronounce-you-man-and-wife), and is used in church ceremonies in which the vicar announces "I now pronounce you man and wife".

Apart from that, on the ELU SE there's an excellent [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300990/252981) by Araucaria describing "**bare coordination**":

> This is when coordinated noun phrases (NPs) which we would otherwise expect to take a determiner of some description appear "bare" with no determiner or article at all. By coordinated, we mean that they appear in phrases using the coordinators *and, or, but* and so forth (some people call coordinators *coordinating conjunctions*). The reason that they seem to be able to appear like this is because they are in such coordinations.
>
> Here are some more examples:
>
> - A black cat and a brown dog were fighting in the street. Cat and dog were equally filthy.
> - Are you man or mouse?
> - I had pen and paper ready to make notes.
> - Mother and child were said to be recovering well.
> - He appeared to be millionaire and homeless vagabond at the same time.
> - Nothing is so sacred as love between husband and wife.